# Apache POI convert cell to int

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, apache-poi

I use Apache POI to upload and read the file. This is my code:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public void addPersonne(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
        ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);
        FileInputStream f =  (FileInputStream) file.getInputStream();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(f); 
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);        
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
            Personne per = new Personne();
            per.setNumero(df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(0)));            
            persorepo.save(per);  
        }               
    }
```

I get an error because the object that I get is of type cell not int.
Please what should I do to convert cell to int

Comment: Check if it is actually a number or not, and if it is, fetch the cell numeric value?

Comment: `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` always gets a `String`. If you need other types, you need using the alternative way showed in https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents.